# How to use 'not start-with' attribute of xpath in selenium to skip certain websites in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've written a code which asks the user for input and opens duckduckgo to search for the website related to that input value. In the search results, I want to open the website which doesn't start with the website mentioned by me in `//a[not(starts-with(@href, 'website'))]`.This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
import pyautogui
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException

stuff = input()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.implicitly_wait(30)
browser.maximize_window()

browser.get("http://www.duckduckgo.com")
elem = browser.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()

elem.send_keys(stuff)
elem.submit()

matched_elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[not(starts-with(@href, "https://it.wikipedia.org/"))]' or '//a[not(starts-with(@href, "https://www.facebook.com"))]')

if matched_elements:
    matched_elements[0].click()
```

Suppose if the user has entered this input:- `Regina Pacis, Reggio nell'Emilia, 42124` and the search results are these:-

[image]

I want the code to skip over the `wikipedia` and `facebook` search results and click on the link highlighted in red. But instead of that, the code goes back to duckduckgo.

I know I can easily achieve the result by:-

```
match_elements = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('result__url__domain')
match_elements[2].click()
```

But the search results are dynamic which will change as per user input. I'd really appreciate if you guys could help me

Comment: I don't see a pattern to work with. Do you want to click on the results of a particular domain or the domain can change?

Comment: I want to click on the domain. Basically, what I want to do is create sort of a blacklist of websites like `wikipedia` , `facebook` which get skipped over every time I run this code and the automation clicks on the domain below that blacklisted website

Comment: ***"I want to click on the domain."*** -  Why no just filter the results and click on the ones that contain the actual domain? The blacklisted domain list may be infinite.

Comment: I can't. I'm asking the user for input, so every time the search result will be different in duckduckgo. So, there is no actual domain here. I just want to add these 2 websites which start with facebook and wikipedia in blacklist and if these websites doesn't exist, the automation just clicks on the first domain that pops up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
dom_bl = ["wikipedia.org", "facebook.com"]
match_elements = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('result__url')
for link in match_elements:
    url = link.get_attribute("href")
    if any(dom in url for dom in dom_bl):
        continue
    link.click()
    break
```

Comment: Hi @CONvid19 , I've asked a question similar to this one, here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61458687/how-to-click-on-a-search-engine-result-if-it-matches-the-searched-value , can you please look at it?