# Beautiful soup returns empty array

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using beautiful soup to find the first hit from a google search.

Looking for "Stack Overflow" it should find https://www.stackoverflow.com

The code is mainly taken from [here](http://from%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43530930) However, it suddenly stopped working with results[0] being index out of range.
    `print results[0] IndexError: list index out of range`

I suspect it's a cache problem as it was working fine and then stopped without changing the code. I've also rebooted and cleared the cache but still no results.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import webbrowser # for webrowser, duh!
import re


#------------------------------------------------
def write_it(s, f):
  # w for over write
  file = open(f, "w")
  file.write(s)
  file.close()

#------------------------------------------------
def URL_encode_space(s):
  return re.sub(r"\s", "%20", s)
#------------------------------------------------
def URL_decode_space(s):
  return re.sub(r"%20", " ", s)
#------------------------------------------------


urlBase = "https://google.com"
searchRequest = "Stack Overflow"

print searchRequest
searchRequest = URL_encode_space(searchRequest)

# String literal for HTML quote
q = "%22" # is a "


numOfResults = 10

myURL = urlBase + "/search?q=" + q + searchRequest + q + "&num={" + str(numOfResults) + "}"

page = requests.get(myURL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
links = soup.findAll("a")
results = []

for link in links:

  link_href = link.get('href')
  if "url?q=" in link_href and not "webcache" in link_href:
    print (link.get('href').split("?q=")[1].split("&sa=U")[0])
    results.append(link.get('href').split("?q=")[1].split("&sa=U")[0])

  print results[0]

# open web browser?
webbrowser.open(myURL)
```

I can obviously check the 'len(results)' to remove the error but that doesn't explain why it no longer works.

Comment: urls change. Code which works for some urls doesn't work for others. Exactly what is happening here isn't clear, but it isn't surprising that an attempt to extract information from urls of a very specific form stops working at some point.

Comment: if you do a `print(link_href)` and `break` inside the loop, you'll see the first url doesn't satisfy the `if` criteria and when you do `results[0]`, you get the error. may be you need to indent the `print(results[0])` block inside the `if` block.

Comment: If the page you are parsing in changing constantly, it could be that the first iteration the if condition is not satisfied, so results will be empty. You can maybe try to print results outside the loop

Comment: I suspect the code stopped worked as google considered it "Unusual traffic from your computer network"

Answer (score 0):

Just like people said above it doesn't clear what could cause the problem.

Make sure you're using `user agent`.

I took this code from my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66823438/15164646) (scraping headings, summary, and links from google search results).

Code and full [example](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-scrape-headingarticle-sum-linkpythonbs4#main.py):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=java&oq=java',
                    headers=headers).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

summary = []

for container in soup.findAll('div', class_='tF2Cxc'):
    heading = container.find('h3', class_='LC20lb DKV0Md').text
    article_summary = container.find('span', class_='aCOpRe').text
    link = container.find('a')['href']

    summary.append({
        'Heading': heading,
        'Article Summary': article_summary,
        'Link': link,
    })

print(json.dumps(summary, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi to get these results.
It's a paid API with a free trial.

Part of JSON:

```json
{
  "position": 1,
  "title": "Java | Oracle",
  "link": "https://www.java.com/",
  "displayed_link": "https://www.java.com",
  "snippet": "Java Download. » What is Java? » Need Help? » Uninstall. About Java. Go Java Java Training Java + Greenfoot Oracle Code One Oracle Academy for ..."
}
```

Code to integrate:

```
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "stackoverflow",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results["organic_results"]:
   print(f"Link: {result['link']}")
```

Output:

```
Link: https://stackoverflow.com/
Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow
Link: https://stackoverflow.blog/
Link: https://stackoverflow.blog/podcast/
Link: https://www.linkedin.com/company/stack-overflow
Link: https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/stack-overflow
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.